# Failed to start snmpd.service on UBUNTU Linux OS

Tags: server, snmp

I updated snmpd.conf file under /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf.
snmpd.conf file contains the following information,

- sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
- sysContact     Me me@example.org
- sysServices    72
- master  agentx
- agentaddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161
- view   all  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
- view   all  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
- rocommunity public default -V all
- rocommunity6 public default -V all
- rouser authPrivUser authpriv -V systemonly

Then i restarted snmpd service (**sudo service snmpd restart**)
when i check the status of the service (**sudo service snmpd status**),i am getting following error,

Please help me on this error...

**Error:**

```
● snmpd.service - Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snmpd.service; enabled; vendor preset:>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-04-27 17:08:36 IST; 8s a>
    Process: 11112 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/agentx (code=exited, sta>
    Process: 11113 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -LOw -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp>
   Main PID: 11113 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 27 17:08:36 prabs-linux systemd[1]: Starting Simple Network Management Prot>
Apr 27 17:08:36 prabs-linux systemd[1]: Started Simple Network Management Proto>
Apr 27 17:08:36 prabs-linux snmpd[11113]: Error opening specified endpoint "udp>
Apr 27 17:08:36 prabs-linux snmpd[11113]: Server Exiting with code 1
Apr 27 17:08:36 prabs-linux systemd[1]: snmpd.service: Main process exited, cod>
Apr 27 17:08:36 prabs-linux systemd[1]: snmpd.service: Failed with result 'exit>
lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and now I see that the problem is with the udp6:[::1]:161 (I assume an ipv6 address). Remove this and then restart service snmpd and the error should go and you get an active state.
J